# How to recover the file deleted in Dreamweaver?

Tags: dreamweaver

I  deleted files accidentally in Dreamweaver.
How to recover the file ?

Answer (score 0):

I use Dreamweaver since many years. I don't know this function. Here are the possibilities I see:

- You should recover the file fom your repositoty if you use that.
- Or maybe you could also try to recover thatfile with the windows recovery functions.
- You could try to run a file recovery program.
- Recover that file from its orginal source if that is not your work.
- Recover that file from the webspace ehere the file is online.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a local file, it ends up in your Recycle Bin (on Windows at least).

Files deleted through FTP are lost and may be only recovered by storage recovery software.

*(I know the question is 2 years old)*